# ggplot2 x axis limits exceeded

Tags: r, ggplot2

If I have x axis limits set like this:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100), breaks = c(0,20,40,60,80,100))
```

but once in a while my data can exceed 100 because of precision like 100.001, what is the best way to handle this?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What would you like to happen with a value of `100.001`? Should it be excluded? Should it appear at `x=100`? Does the `.001` have any value, or could you round your values or put a cap on them, ie. `x[x > 100] <- 100` ?

Comment: I love that idea! No there is no value in any value beyond 100.0. Thanks!

Comment: You may use `scale_y_continuous(..., oob = squish)`

Answer (score 0):

In you place I set up greater limits, like c(0, 105). If the values will not grow up beyond this or will change the meaning of the visualization, maybe worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

If 100 is the maximum possible value of `x` and you're sure that values greater than that represent rounding errors or mistakes, you could cap the values to the maximum logical value (100 in this case):

```
x <- c(0,2,3,88, 99, 100, 100.01, 100.2)
x[x > 100] <- 100
x
[1]   0   2   3  88  99 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I went with this:

```
 scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,101), breaks = c(0,20,40,60,80,100))
```

The chart still looks great.